# How to mock sharepoint methods and objects

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm trying to write unit test for my functionality where I'm usuing sharepoint Client context.
For example:

```
var list = _context.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(listGuid));
```

How can I create Sharepoint List od ListItemCollection to mock it or add some sample data?

Comment: For testing our SharePoint project we used [Typemock Isolator](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fmockingasharepointsite.htm). You can check their examples to see if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock both sharepoint sites and collections with [this](http://www.typemock.com/docs/?book=Isolator&page=Documentation%2FHtmlDocs%2Fsample2explicitlyfakinganspitemcollection.htm) utility.
It gives you the ability to control the behavior of your Lists and to invoke just what you need.